# Status bar color change onclick button in sliverappbar

Tags: flutter, dart

In flutter, do someone guess what the cause why change the color of the status bar when I click the button in a `SliverAppBar`?

[image]

I set the styles and that work until click the button:

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
    statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
    statusBarBrightness: Brightness.light,
  ));
```

Comment: try to wrap with safeArea